# I would like to know how to to Inject a datasource from one component into another in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, datasource, devextreme

I currently have two components. My first component contains a dx datagrid that contains a dataSource that is working correctly.

Component 1

```
 <dx-data-grid id="gridContainer" *ngIf="!showSpinner"
                  (onRowUpdating)="onRowUpdating($event)"
                  (onRowInserted)="onRowInserting($event)"
                  (onRowRemoved)="onRowRemoved($event)"
                  (onCellPrepared)="onCellPrepared($event)"
                  (onToolbarPreparing)="onToolbarPreparing($event)"
                  [dataSource]="dataSource"
                  [remoteOperations]="false"
                  [allowColumnReordering]="true"
                  [rowAlternationEnabled]="true"
                  [showBorders]="true">
      <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>
      <dxo-pager
        [showPageSizeSelector]="true"
        [allowedPageSizes]="[10, 25, 50, 100]"
      ></dxo-pager>

      <dxo-search-panel
        [visible]="true"
        [highlightCaseSensitive]="true"
      ></dxo-search-panel>

      <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
      <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Name" dataType="string"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="expression" caption="Expression" dataType="string"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="longterm" caption="Online Range" dataType="boolean"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="persisted" caption="Persisted" dataType="boolean"></dxi-column>
      <dxi-column dataField="status" caption="Ready" dataType="boolean"></dxi-column>

      <dxo-editing
        mode="form"
        [allowUpdating]="true"
        [allowDeleting]="true"
        [allowAdding]="true"
        [confirmDelete]="true">
        <dxo-form labelLocation="top">
          <dxi-item itemType="group" colCount="2" colSpan="2">
            <dxi-item dataField="name" [items]="dataSource">
              <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Name is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
              <dxi-validation-rule type="custom" message="This LAS name already exists or the name is too long" [validationCallback]="validateLAS"></dxi-validation-rule>
            </dxi-item>
            <dxi-item dataField="expression" [items]="dataSource">
              <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Expression is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
              <dxi-validation-rule type="custom" message="This expression already exists or This expression is too long" [validationCallback]="validateExpression"></dxi-validation-rule>
            </dxi-item>
            <dxi-item dataField="longterm">
            </dxi-item>
            <dxi-item dataField="persisted">
            </dxi-item>
          </dxi-item>
        </dxo-form>
      </dxo-editing>
    </dx-data-grid>
dataSource: any[];

 getLasList(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
      this.lasManagerService
        .getLasList()
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          const element: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.dx-button-text');

          if (element) {
            if (element.innerText === 'Save') {
              this.errorCount = 0;
              this.nextLoad(60000);
            }
          } else {
            this.dataSource = data;
            this.errorCount = 0;
            this.nextLoad(60000);
          }
          resolve(true);
        });
    }));
  }

 openHelp() {
        this.factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LasManagerHelpComponent).componentType;
        const selector = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LasManagerHelpComponent).selector;
    
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
        dialogConfig.width = '1000px';
        dialogConfig.height = '100%';
        dialogConfig.id = 'modal-help';
        dialogConfig.data = {widget : {title: 'las_manager.las_details', selector}, factory: this.factory};
    
    
        this.matDialog.open(HelpDialogComponent, dialogConfig,);
      }
```

I am injecting into component 2 using   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {} and I am able to access the datagrid but it is saying that no datasource is set. Any ideas?

Component 2

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4  class="modal-title" id="modal-full-title">Add LAS</h4>
  <button  aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
    <span  aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
</div>
  <app-las-manager></app-las-manager>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
  <button class="btn btn-primary footer-button" title="Apply and Close" (click)="onApply()">Apply and Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary footer-button" title="Cancel" (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

export class AddLasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddLasComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onApply() {

  }

  closeModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data` injection only works if you're opening the component using `dialog.open()`

**In Component 1**

```js
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  dialogRef?: MatDialogRef<AddLasComponent>;

  openDialog() {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddLasComponent, { data: this.dataSource });
  }
```

**In AddLasComponent**

```js
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddLasComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any[]
  ) {}
```

See the docs for more info: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not fully following, where in my component 1 should this go?

Comment: @Matt I've updated the answer to be more clear

Comment: Would there be a way for me to do this using the existing open function I have? I have added it called openHelp()

Comment: I don't understand, why are you opening something called a `HelpDialogComponent` but attempting to inject data into `AddLasComponent`?

Comment: The HelpDialogComponent is a template for a modal which the datagrid will be inside of and displayed to AddLASComponent.

Comment: You need to inject the data into the dialog, not this other component.

Comment: That's where I am stuck. I have tried to add the datasource by this.dataSource in the dialogConfig.data but no luck.

Comment: Add this line to the constructor of your dialog component: `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any` the data will then be accessible in that component after it has been opened with the MatDialog service. You're currently trying to inject into some other component.

Comment: Sadly I have that added already. My gird is successfully displaying in the modal it just contains no records and says data source isn't specified

Comment: I think you should add the relevant code.